# Restriction of solr results?

Tags: solr, alfresco, solr4

I am using alfresco-5.0.d and Solr 4. My question is "is there any restriction to fetch more then 1000 files at a time in alfresco".

I found one tutorial

> http://fcorti.com/2013/05/01/alfresco-1000-results-lucene/

Can anyone verify the above or add more info about Solr4.

Answer (score 1):

That restriction does not apply to solr. However there is a restriction of 10000 rows returned by default and if you expect more results you should use the paging mechanism.

Comment: Thanks @billerby   my alfresco has 1000+ same doctype files are there but when i am getting the result so num of result it's showing 1000 only

Answer (score 0):

You might find an answer here:

- [ALF-20567 - SOLR doesnt return more than 1000 objects](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-20567)

Try to add theses two in your /shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties

- system.acl.maxPermissionCheckTimeMillis=25000
- system.acl.maxPermissionChecks=5000
- solr.query.maximumResultsFromUnlimitedQuery=5000